# How Meteor js re-activeness works?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have started learning Meteor and created a demo application.

i want to know when i am inserting data,it will show data at that moment without refreshing screen.

i am not sure meteor uses nodejs+socket or what?

can someone briefly Explain meteorjs inside re-activeness.

Comment: Read [the Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/) or one of the many resources available online to learn about Meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor uses the DDP protocol over web sockets - basically a two way channel between client and server. Use is made of Mongo's notification mechanism (I think using oplog tailing) to send updates to mini-mongo on the client.

Changes to the data cause the collections on the client to refresh, and re-render using the blaze templating engine.

Read more about it here https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/

According to Arthur C Clarke, "Any sufficiently advanced technology can be indistinguishable from magic"